# How to transfer the following Java methods to Python def()

Tags: python, java

```
public static double readNumber(String prompt,double min, double max){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    double value;
    while (true){
        System.out.print(prompt);
        value = scanner.nextFloat();
        if (value >= min && value <= max) {
            break;
        } else
            System.out.println("Enter a value between "+min+" and "+max);
    }
    return value;
}
```

The upper one works. But the following one doesn't jump out of the loop.

```
def readnumber(prompt, minimum, maximum):
    while True:
        value = float(input(prompt))
        if minimum <= value <= maximum:
            return value
        else:
            print(f"a valid value needed between {minimum} and {maximum}")
            break
```

It doesn't work the same way. HELP the new beginner please

Comment: can you please explain what exactly this method do

Comment: if I input a number into this method then it should be between the min and max values, if not it will give a hint and ask you to input it again

Comment: When I run your Python example, it _always_ breaks out of the loop after prompting one time. If the `value` is between the `minimum` and the `maximum`, it executes the `return value` statement, and the function returns the value. Otherwise, it executes the `break` statement, and the function returns `None`.  Are you sure that the code you copied into your question is the same as the code that you are trying to run?

Comment: @HYZ just remove the `break` statement

Comment: what's wrong with putting in a bit of print statements or using  a debugger, before posting here?  there's nothing all that specific to Python going on.  welcome aboard, but try to aim for a bit less trivial questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You have the break in the wrong case. in the java method you break when the value is > minimum and < than maximum, but in the python code you break the loop in the other case

Answer (score 0):

For me it works perfectly fine. To use the function just put it somewhere and make sure to make the prompt a string like for example in this usecase of the function:

```
print(readnumber("input a number: ", 2, 4))
```

Edit: For contiuos asking for a number remove the break statement in the else clause

Comment: It's supposed to continue prompting for input until the user types a number in the given range. Did you try entering a number that was out-of-range?

Comment: But if I input the wrong number how I can make it return to let me input the correct number again? Thanks

Comment: @HYZ remove the break statement

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extra line of code and create a flag and change the flag
e.g.,

```
flag = true
```

and use

```
while(flag)
```

Then instead of break, you can change the flag to false so the loop stops explicitly rather than implicitly